# simulate uiview bounds with physical size of iphone 6/ iphone 6 plus on ipad air(v1)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create UIView with bounds that will be the same size as **physical** screen size of iphone6/iphone 6 plus, and run this in ipad air(v1)

Now, I read this info :

> Size for iPhone 6 Plus with @3x scaling (Apple name: Retina HD 5.5),
>   Coordinate space: 414 x 736 points and 1242 x 2208 pixels, 401 ppi,
>   screen physical size is 2.7 x 4.8 in or 68 x 122 mm.
>
> Size for iPhone 6 with @2x scaling (Apple name: Retina HD 4.7),
>   Coordinate space: 375 x 667 points and 750 x 1334 pixels, 326 ppi,
>   screen physical size is 2.3 x 4.1 in or 58 x 104 mm.

What is the correct bounds/coordinate space I need to set in my UIView that will show on the ipad, the **physical** screen size for iphone 6/iphone 6 plus ?

Comment: Get that same info for the iPad Air and do the math.

Answer (score 0):

You should take coordinate space values as bound size for your view and align it as you want, for iphone 6+ it is 414 x 736 and for 6 it is 375 x 667.

Comment: But the scale and ppi are diffrent. I already test this coordinate space..and the results are not : 68 x 122 mm / 58 x 104 mm in the iphone simulate screen (on the ipad screen)

Comment: you won't be able to repeat ppi, because it's device specific feature. You only can scale. You won't be able to reproduce 3x on 2x device. And is there a big difference, when you compare view with 375 x 667 with 58x104 mm real device?

Comment: Not too big, but I thought there is something I'm missing that everyone use and know.
I guess, it's not good idea to use the physical screen size to simulate iphone on ipad.